# rails-api nested attributes for a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic association like so:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contractable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients, :as => :contractable
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients, :as => :contractable
end
```

If I want to send a POST to my controller for clients (`POST /clients`), when I send the JSON in the request body, how do I specify to create either an individual OR a business and set the association properly?

Ex JSON (not working):

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "Person",
    "contractable": {
      "age": 50
    }
  }
}
```

Also, how do I tell strong_params to allow this to happen?

Comment: How the 2 pieces of JSON that will come for creating either of the object ?

Comment: Anyway, I would add a `type` field ofcourse inside the `contractable` hash. Which will have value `Business` or `Individual`. Based on this value, you will switch. And to know how to create objects with this associations, read http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails

Comment: Yeah, the client model has a contractable_id and contractable_type, but I'm trying to create a nested contractable -- which is either an Individual or a Business.  That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: It has to be nested.  So the client has many "contractables" which can be either individuals or businesses.  How do I created a nested contractable when creating a client?